# MySQL Query "IN" 500,000 Records

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT value FROM table WHERE id IN ("1","2","3", ... "500000")
```

Have a query that reads like the above with about 500,000 values in the parentheses.

Is there a better way of performing a search? This method is very cumbersome/slow.

Comment: How did you get the 500K ids? From another query? Or are they in some list in your application code?

Comment: Where do these 500,000 items come from? If they originate in the DB, you can `join`. Hard to imagine a user typing in 500,000 values :-)

Comment: From a list of data that is not in MySQL. I suppose I could add this data and do JOIN. Would that be faster?

Comment: are they ordered and consecutive? Would `between 1 and 500000` work?

Comment: @reefine: Yes, a JOIN would be faster. See Joe Stefanelli's answer. Especialy if you need to do this multiple times (with same ids or almost the same)

Comment: They are all MD5 hashes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the 500,000 values into another table and join against it.

```
SELECT t.value
    FROM table t
        INNER JOIN NewTempTable n
            ON t.id = n.id
```

Answer (score 2):

you are close to mysql packet size limit (it's 16MB) so it's certainly bad idea.

from which source do you have these half million ids? couldn't you store them in database and perform join?

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

Step 01 : Make a table of the IDs

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lookup_ids;
CREATE TABLE lookup_ids SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE 1=2;
ALTER TABLE lookup_ids ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Step 02 : You INSERT all 500,000 values INTO lookup_ids

Step 03 : Make a decent covering index on `table`

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE INDEX id_value_ndx (id,value);
```

Step 04 : Perform the JOIN

```
SELECT t.value FROM `table` t INNER JOIN lookup_ids i USING (id);
```

or

```
SELECT t.value FROM `table` t NATURAL JOIN lookup_ids i;
```

CAVEAT : Steps 1-3 do not need to be repeated unless you have a different set of lookup ids to load